# How to create a list of many characters in python?

Tags: python, loops

I would like to create a list of size 100 in python that contains the character `x_i` for `i=1...100`. How to do this in Python?

```
['x_1', 'x_2', ..., 'x_100']
```

If it was a list of 10 character I would write it by hand, but a hundred elements?

Comment: `list(map("x_{}".format,range(1,101)))`

Comment: It looks like you may be a beginner; take a look at `for` loops.

Comment: [ "x_" + str(item) for item in range(1,101) ]

Comment: Comments are not for posting short answers.

Comment: Oh, sorry, "have you tried `list(map("x_{}".format,range(1,101)))`?"  We good now?

Comment: @tristan Hahaha.  The comment box itself asks us to avoid answering questions in comments though.

Comment: While I am sure this question has been asked before in a variety of formats and doesn't demonstrate much user effort, we should probably explain why we feel downvotes are necessary to the OP at some point.  (Or vote to close for one reason or another.)

Comment: Six `for`-loop-and-string-formatting answers so far, this question requires at least ten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use list comprehension

```
["x_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my_list = []
for i in xrange(1, 101): #use range if python 3+
  my_list.append('x_{0}'.format(i))

print my_list
```

This is easier to understand if you're just getting started.  Xrange starts at 1 and goes to 101 (exclusive).

Comment: and in python 3 you would have to use `range` instead, for code that is compatible with both I'd recommend using `range` anyway

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be a beginner so here is a simple example:

```
mylist = [] 
for i in range(1, 101): 
    mylist.append('x_'+str(i))      
print(mylist)
```

Comment: haha, I posted almost exactly the same thing as you at the same time.

Comment: String concatenation is different

Answer (score 0):

```
["x_"+str(i) for i in range(1,101)]
```

Using list comprehension.